# Change order pagination options dojo

Tags: pagination, dojo

I make a table with dojo script, but it should see the diferent order of pagination options as that:  1. the page navigation choices,  2. page length menu and, 3. current position display.

I need help with that, how  can I change that?

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/_images/pagination_ui_overview.bmp

Comment: Can you answer the following: What version of Dojo are you using? What style package are you using? example: claro, tundra, ext.., and what type of grid are you using?

Comment: it is 1.8.3 of IBM process designer and package dijit

Comment: Is this a dojox/EnchancedGrid?

Comment: yes it is, for generate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to customize/modify an existing dojo widget you will need to manipulate the dom.

In this specific case you should use selectors like [dojo/dom](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom.html) and [dojo/query](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/query.html) to select the portions of the grid you wish to move and then use [dojo/dom-construct](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-construct.html) to place them in the correct location.

```
domConstruct.place(pageNavigation, positionDisplay, "replace");
```

Here is a jsfiddle which demonstrates a portion of what you are trying to accomplish and is a good starting point http://jsfiddle.net/kagant15/u6edz0b9/